# Private alternatives to LiveDocx

Tags: php, pdf, zend-framework, livedocx

I've been looking for a solution to generate PDF from some data I have on a database. Currently I put it on an HTML and then print to PDF, but they asked me to save directly to PDF. These are documents that vary a lot in design, so before it was easy to change a margin or a font size, but now they asking for a direct PDF output it's more difficult, so I saw that LiveDocx is a great solution for me... but these documents are very private (illneses, income...) and my bosses don't want to send any document to a server. So I'm looking for some other solutions. The perfect workaround is doing what LiveDocx proposes (You have a template in a Docx format that you can modify whenever you want, and then you can send some data to the template to fill the gaps and of course save to PDF) but in my own server. Do you know something like this?

My platform is based on PHP+Zend Framework, so it should be compatible with that.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well instead of using LiveDocx, i found a really cool Library. mPDF an MIT Licensed library that transfers HTML Code to a pdf document. Its simple and great. Let me know if this helped you and if you need more help.

AND ontop of all that, you can write your data directly to the pdf document. You can input an html file into the pdf writer IF you want. If not then yes you can use their write function to write data directly to pdf.

Comment: The "template" being an HTML document. Its the same thing. The HTML document is a middle interpreter, why is that a problem to use.

Comment: your welcome. Please accept this answer if it helped you :)

Comment: It was an awesome solution. It has some troubles with float positioning, but it worked as I wanted!! thank you very much @MakDo

Comment: your super welcome. Glad it worked out ! @jdlcgarcia